# What does variable after declaring a struct mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have these lines:

```
char sendbuf[BUF_SIZ];
struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
```

I understand that **eh** will be equal to that struct, but then it equal's again to that struct and has a variable in front of it? If someone can explain to me I would appreciate it.

Comment: This is casting the address of `sendbuf` to a struct pointer, and then initializing `eh` with that pointer.

Comment: `struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;` is also a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.  And if `sendbuf` isn't correctly aligned for whatever fields `struct ether_header` has, it'll be undefined behavior for that reason, too.

Answer (score 2):

It’s assigning the address of `sendbuf` to `eh` *as though* `sendbuf` were an object of type `struct ether_header`.

There are two reasons to do this:

1. In C, you cannot assign a pointer value of one type to a pointer of a different type without an explicit cast, unless one of the pointers has type `void *`.  You cannot assign a `char *` value to a `struct ether_header *` object without a cast.

   A common (unsafe) practice is to map `struct` types onto arrays of `char` or `unsigned char` by creating a pointer like this.  You can set bytes in the array by accessing members of the struct type like

   ```
   eh->ether_type = 0x0800;
   ```

   .  Then you just send the array over a connection using `fwrite` or something.

It’s unsafe because it’s not guaranteed elements of the struct type will be aligned correctly, and strictly speaking the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of the variable definition:

1. First the actual variable definition

   ```
   struct ether_header *eh
   ```

   This defines the variable `eh` as being a pointer to `struct ether_header`.
2. The second part is the initialization

   ```
   eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf
   ```

   First of all it takes the character array `sendbuf` and gets a pointer to the first element of the array (`sendbuf` in this context will *decay* to `&sendbuf[0]`), then cast that pointer to pretend it's a pointer to `struct ether_header`.

   Then it initializes `eh` to be the same as the pointer on the right-hand side of the `=`.

Note that the second part ***isn't*** assignment, it's *initialization*.

All of this should be pretty clear if you read any decent beginners book.